# How to recall an archived dataset if it is the current generation of a GDG

Tags: mainframe, zos

I tried 'HRECALL GTEMP.BATCH.FILE(0)' to recall the latest GDG generation and it returned and invalid dsn name error message.

However, using a similiar command, 'HRECALL GTEMP.BATCH.FLATFILE', recalls flat file as expected.

What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: `HRECALL` is not `JCL`. 

In JCL it would be massively rare that you want a `version`  and entirely normal that you want a `generation`. 

It would be extremely curious if HRECALL, which is not JCL, worked with a *relative* generation. 

Specify the full DSN that you want (with the GnnnnV00 bit), You've used a wrong, and impossible, name. If you can clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do, one of @piet.t's options will be suitable. It is important to know whether the dataset being recalled is used within this job, or at some un-predetermined later time.

Comment: I've tidied the question for you, but please learn the difference between JCL and stuff which is not JCL, and between Version and Generation as they apply to GDGs.

Comment: When there is any error message which you want to refer to here, please highlight it in your emulator screen, copy it, and then paste it in your question (or answer). Before posting a question look up the error message and see if the explanation and suggested actions answer your question. 90% or more of the time, you will resolve your problem that way. IBM's Knowledge Centre is the new way to look up errors on the web. LookAt is the old way. And there are also message manuals available.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are executing the command using some flavour of the TSO-Terminal-Monitor-Program, e.g. `IKJEFT01`.

Your problem is that TSO doesn't support addressing `GDG`s using relative generations, so it will interpret your `(0)` as a PDS-member-name instead of a generation.

So what are your options?

1. Write a REXX-procedure to determine the DSN of the latest generation (e.g. `GTEM.BATCH.FILE.G1234V00`) and recall it.
2. You can use JES-mechanisms to recall the file(s) in a separate job-step:

   //RECALL   EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
   //DATASET1 DD DSN=GTEMP.BATCH.FILE(0),DISP=SHR
   //DATASET2 DD DSN=GTEMP.BATCH.FILE2(0),DISP=SHR

Option 2. is easy to implement but depending on your needs it might have two downsides:

- The datasets will be recalled one after the other while `HRECALL` might recall several datasets in parallel
- The step will only end after all datasets have been recalled (which might also be an advantage depending on your needs)

Comment: There's a design issue, which is whether '(0)' is always the actual generation required. The batch-TSO with Rexx (and the initial plain HRECALL if it could work) suffer the problem of having their control-cards ignored for the purposes of job setup/selection and may die unexpectedly or get an unexpected (0) generation. Option 2 can also be used for the fully-named dataset. HRECALL allows NOWAIT. Without NOWAIT being used, I can see no reason not to use IEFBR14....

Comment: Are you sure about the first bullet? I think in modern times, the recalling when using IEFBR14 (at least, not sure about "any old program") is much cleverer than it used to be. If recalled from tape (or "tape") all requests for the same volume will be done together, in sequence order, without even having to be specified that way.

Comment: @Bill Woodger Before posting I tried recalling two datasets of mine and it really looked like it was retrieving them sequentially. But it might also be a matter of waiting for the right tape being mounted. I had hoped my joblog would generate some "recalling..."-messages but there were none :(

Comment: While preparing my answer I was trying to find something definitive in the docs. Couldn't, and then you'd already posted :-) If on physical tape of some type, it can only be sequential, but there will be no silly rewinds or multiple mounts. I think :-)